# XNA Can't create multiple instances?

Tags: xna, instance

I am trying to build a very simple XNA project.
Every 5 seconds a new ball should be spawned which will bounce of the walls.
For some reason it doesn't create multiple instances of my ball. I can't seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Was hoping someone here could help me discover my errors.

Here is my code Game1.cs class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace BallBounce
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    public static SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    Ball ball;
    Ball ball2;

    Ball[] balls;
    int maxBalls = 1;

    Texture2D ballTexture;
    Texture2D ballTexture2;

    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 position2;

    int spawnTime = 0;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        ballTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Bitmap1");
        ballTexture2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Bitmap2");

        Random r = new Random();
        int randomNumberX = r.Next(0, 400);
        int randomNumberY = r.Next(0, 400);

        position = new Vector2(randomNumberX, randomNumberY);
        position2 = new Vector2(randomNumberY, randomNumberX);

        ball = new Ball(this, ballTexture, position);
        ball2 = new Ball(this, ballTexture2, position2);

        Components.Add(ball);
       // Components.Add(ball2);

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // TODO: Add your update logic here
        spawnTime += (int)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
       // Console.WriteLine(spawnTime + " " + maxBalls);
        if(spawnTime >= 500)
        {
            maxBalls += 1;

            for(int i = 0; i < maxBalls; i++)
            {
                //balls[i] = new Ball(this,ballTexture);
                //Components.Add(balls[i]);
            }

            spawnTime = 0;
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

}

And here is my Ball.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace BallBounce
{
public class Ball : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.DrawableGameComponent
{
    Texture2D texture;
    Vector2 speed = new Vector2(4,6);
    Vector2 position;
    Color color = Color.Blue;

    public Ball(Game1 game, Texture2D texture, Vector2 position)
        : base(game)
    {
        this.texture = texture;
        Console.WriteLine("=========================BAL---------------");

        this.position = position;

        Random random = new Random();

        int red = random.Next(0, 255);
        int green = random.Next(0,255);
        int blue = random.Next(0,255);

        color = new Color(red,green,blue);

        Console.WriteLine(position);

    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        this.position = this.position += speed;

        if (this.position.Y >= (GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - this.texture.Height))
        {
            speed.Y = speed.Y * -1;
        }
        if (this.position.Y <= 0)
        {
            speed.Y = speed.Y * -1;
        }
        if (this.position.X >= (GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - this.texture.Width))
        {
            speed.X = speed.X * -1;
        }
        if (this.position.X <= 0)
        {
            speed.X = speed.X * -1;
        }

    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Game1.spriteBatch.Begin();
        Game1.spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, color);
        Game1.spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're recreating all balls in some array, adding one more every 500 milliseconds (which is 0.5 of a second really). You should just add a new ball to some global list of balls, instead of rewriting all existing balls as you do now.

So I guess you could do this:

```
if(spawnTime >= 500)
{
    Components.Add(new Ball(this, ballTexture));            

    spawnTime = 0;
}
```

Your approach doesn't look good, though. Are you sure you want to add balls straight to `Components`?

Comment: Ah thank you, your piece of code did the job.
Why would i not want to do that? Are there any limitations to this approach?

Comment: Well, there must be some limitations, like no more than 10 million objects, I don't really know. It's just that you might want to keep all ball instances in some list that you can directly call and modify, but that is if you plan on doing anything besides creating the balls. If not, then I guess you're fine.